# Why is my instance variable coming up as undefined when I ask for user input in my init method

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, user-input

When I ask the user for input into my class the variable comes up as undefined.
When i run it in my `__init__` method

```
import random
import math
players=[]
player_names=[]
cards=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'kings','queens','aces']
class  Player:
    def __init__(self,name,money,cardl,bust,bet=None):
        
        self.name=name
        self.name=input('enter in your name')
        while cls.name  in player_names:
                print('username taken')
                cls.name=input('Enter in name')
        self.money=money
        money=0
        self.bet=bet
        bet=float(input("What is your bet"))
        self.busted=busted
        self.cardl=[]
        self.cardl.append(random.sample(cards,1))
        self.cardl.append(random.sample(cards,1))
        self.busted=False
player=Player(name,money,cardl,bust,bet)
players.append(player)
print('Welcome',player.name)
 
class dealer(Player):
        pass
```

I expected for the user to be allowed to start inputting values into the variables but I got

```
player=Player(name,money,cardl,bust,bet)
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

So I decided to run the `__init__` method by:

```
__init__()
```

NameError: name '__init__' is not defined

Comment: You need to give values to all the variables before you can use them in the argument list. Like `name = input("What is your name? ")`

Comment: Since the method asks the user for the name, there's no need to have it in the parameter list.

Comment: I think your `__init__()` method doesn't really need any parameters. It asks the user for the name, and all the other attributes are set to default values.

Comment: It's very confusing because you do `self.busted = busted` (note that the parameter is actually named `bust`) and then a few lines later you do `self.busted = False`. So if you're going to set it to `False`, why did you first set it to `busted`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables do not yet exist when you call the class constructor, so the object cannot be created. You could initialize them empty, but then they should be initialized correctly right away. The check for the player name can be implemented this way:

```
import gc

player_name_list = []

# get all the current player names
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if isinstance(obj, Player):
        player_name_list.append(obj.name)

name=input('enter in your name')
while name in player_name_list:
    print('username taken')
    name=input('Enter in name')
```

Comment: Thank you this helped. Also I  got a question do people on stack overflow answer questions randomly in their spare time, because they are bored, or do you say to yourself I need to help at least one person today?

Comment: @somehelplease glad I could help. I would appreciate if you mark my comment as the correct answer! For my part, I typically scroll through stackoverflow while code is compiling or queries are running  ;)